# How do I get the content of a subdirectory I've specified in a sparse checkout to the root of my folder?

Tags: git

In this case, I'm using a *dist* folder, where the front end lies. Just want those files on my web server, all I'm getting is a dist folder with my application files inside it.

Comment: Is this the action you wish to apply to deploy your code on your production server ?

Comment: Yes, pretty much